# Corona SDK - Use scrollview listener to move image with scrolling momentum

Tags: lua, scrollview, coronasdk

I want to move my "background" image with the scrolling action in the scrollview and I want the background to move slower than the content of the scrollview to give the impression of depth.  Here is the code I'm working with.  It works, but only if the screen is receiving a touch.  I want it to continue moving with the scrolling momentum. What am I doing wrong?

```
local function scrollListener( event )
    local phase = event.phase
    local x, y = scrollView:getContentPosition()

    if phase == "moved" then
       if event.limitReached then
        -- do nothing
       else
            bg.x = x  /3
       end
    end

    return true
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to implement some parallax scrolling.
You should get the drag distance from the scrollview scrollListener( event ) "move" event

```
local isListening = false

local function scrollListener( event )
    local phase = event.phase

    if "began" == phase then
        if(isListening) then
            Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", updateBgPos )
            isListening = true
        end
    elseif phase == "moved" then
       if event.limitReached then
           Runtime:removeEventListener( updateBgPos )
           isListening = false
       end
    end

    return true
end

local function updateBgPos(event) 
    local x, y = scrollView:getContentPosition()
    bg.x = x / 3
end
```

Comment: Are you sure `Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", updateBgPos )` is right? Wouldn't that end up `Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", nil )`?